# Can I say "Ok, let's decide it that way" to wrap up a meeting, or agreeing with someone's suggestion? Is it unnatural?

Tags: word-choice

Can I say "Ok, let's decide it that way" to wrap up a meeting, or agreeing with someone's suggestion. For example, my friend said " I can only meet you at 3 pm tomorrow because I'll be busy for the rest of the day" and I replied "Ok, let's decide it that way".

Comment: I wouldn't say it's unacceptable, but 'Let's decide it that way' is almost always used with the sense 'Let's use that method to decide the issue'. 'Let's go with that' is far more natural-sounding here.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would not be correct usage. To wrap up at meeting, you might say, "OK, it's decided." To agree with what someone has said, you might say, "OK, let's do it that way."